# Using the newline character to break a loop in c++

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to break a `for` loop using enter in the visual studio console.

```
do {
    std::cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == '\n')
        break;
    lineStorage[lineLength] = userInput;
    lineLength++;
} while(true);
```

This is what I have so far, but the newline character won't work for what I need it to. Any suggestions or insight would help.

P.S. I cannot use a sentinel value other than the newline character resulting from the enter button.

P.S. More context:

```
char lineStorage[80] = { 'a' };
char userInput = ' ';
const char lineEnd = '\n';

int lineLength = 0;

std::cout << "Enter a line:";

do {
    std::cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == '\n')
        break;
    lineStorage[lineLength] = userInput;
    lineLength++;
} while (true);
```

Comment: @Elliott Any basic inputs recreate this issue, but if I must.

"faifjfosijf sfeasiof" [Enter]

Comment: Why not using `std::cin.get(userInput)` ?

Comment: @treeTallAsian, fair enough. I think' I read your question too quickly. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading with `>>` by default skips whitespace, and a newline is whitespace.  I suggest using `getline()` instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
    if (!getline(std::cin, userInput) || userInput.empty())
        break;
    lineStorage[lineLength] = userInput;
    lineLength++;
}
```

If your `lineStorage` is really supposed to store individual words, you can split `userInput` on spaces before storing the words.

---

Edit: now that you've shown that `userInput` is a single character, I think you should just use [`std::cin.get(userInput)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to read one character at a time.  That will let you get the newlines in the style of your original code.

Comment: It would probably help for me to clarify that lineStorage is storing up to 80 char variables.

Comment: Thanks! I was oblivious to the fact that white space wasn't read by the >> operators.

Answer (score 1):

I like the other answer better, but something like this should also work:

```
do {
  cin.get(userInput);
  if (userInput == 10) {
    break;
  } else { 
    lineStorage[lineLength] = userInput;
    lineLength++;
  }
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

more clear will be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char t[70]={0},x;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%[^ ^\n]%c",t ,&x);
        if(x == '\n') break;
    }
}
```